# Tensorflow step size incredibly small to prevent errors?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to do a simple linear regression problem using Gradient Descent with Tensorflow, but unless I set my step size really, really small, the weight and bias balloon and overflow almost immediately.  Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Read the data
COLUMNS = ["url", "title_length", "article_length", "keywords", "shares"]
data = np.genfromtxt("OnlineNewsPopularitySample3.csv", delimiter=',', names=COLUMNS)

# We're looking for shares based on article_length
article_length = tf.placeholder("float")
shares = tf.placeholder("float")

# Set up the variables we're going to use
initial_m = 1.0
initial_b = 1.0
w = tf.Variable([initial_m, initial_b], name="w")

predicted_shares = tf.multiply(w[0], article_length) + w[1]
error = tf.square(predicted_shares - shares)

# This is as big as I can make it; any larger, and I have problems.
step_size = .000000025
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(step_size).minimize(error)

model = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:

   # First initialize all the variables
   session.run(model)

   # Now we're going to run the optimizer
   for i in range(100000):

      session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={article_length: data['article_length'], shares: data['shares']})

      if (i % 100 == 0):
         print (session.run(w))

   # Once it's done, we need to get the value of w so we can display it.    
   w_value = session.run(w)

   print("Predicted model: {a:.3f}x + {b:.3f}".format(a=w_value[0], b=w_value[1]))
```

So basically, when I run this, the outputs become "NaN" almost immediately.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very low learning rate means a very small update to the weights. In your case, even a relatively small learning rate is blowing up your weights, its because the weight updates (dE/dW) seems to be very large. And the update is a function of the output Error. If the labels are large values, your squared error will be high at the start as the predictions will be quite low. Try scaling the outputs to avoid this problem.

Comment: You may want to `scale` the  `inputs and outputs` and rescale it back  during inference.